# Spring Boot 1 and Gradle: ClassNotFoundException SpringApplicationBuilder

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I've got a Gradle configuration for a Spring Boot 1.5 application. It runs fine in Spring Tool Suite, but `gradlew build` creates a jar file with no jar files in the BOOT-INF folder. This of course prevents the successful execution of the jar file:

```
java -jar build\libs\myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/builder/SpringApplicationBuilder
        at myapp.boot.Application.runWithContextHierarchy(Application.java:50)
        at myapp.boot.Application.main(Application.java:33)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:94)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        ... 10 more
```

`build.gradle` excerpt:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '1.5.22.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

dependencies {
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that Spring Boot 1 isn't able to work with `implementation` dependencies, but with (deprecated) `compile` dependencies.

Working `build.gradle` dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    ....
}
```